# Is it better practice to keep a static list of every game object as they are instantiated, or to use raycasts to find every gameobject periodically?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

If I want to check for the closest gameObject with the class "Enemy", I have two options:

1. I can build a static list of every Enemy gameObject that is instantiated, and find the closest one using the list, or
2. I can use physics raycasts to find every Enemy gameObject, put them into a list, and find the closest one like that.

They both seem about equal; if anything, it seems like building a static list would have better performance since there's no raycasting involved, but on the other hand using approach 2 seems like it is more extensible for further changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds quite opinion based but here is what I would do

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly List<Enemy> _instances = new ();
    public static IReadOnlyList<Enemy> Instances => _instances;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

This way you always have the actual list of existing instances without needing to poll them all the time.

Now you can get the closest one e.g. using Linq

```
var closestEnemy = Enemy.Instances.OrderBy(e => (e.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();
```

Using physics is no good approach if you need to find all the `Enemy` instances anyway.

---

Depends on your use case though. You might only want to get those within a certain range. In that case you could again either use above approach and filter on a specific distance or you could use e.g. an [`OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html). Performance wise I claim that Physics will always be worse.

Comment: Great answer, I'm curious what the roles of the two different lists are (List<Enemy> _instances vs IReadOnlyList<Enemy> Instances), and the significance of their protection levels (private static readonly vs public static)

Comment: one is the actual list field .. the other one is a read-only **property** => only this class is allowed to modify the list, others can only read the property. The `readonly` just means this list is only created once and then exists forever .. there is never another list instance assigned to this field

Comment: What's the difference between this and a List<Enemy> with public get; protected set;?

Comment: @frandude and no .. scratch that :D actually you can not. You need the field as a `List` explicitly, because the property is only a `IReadOnlyList` .. you wouldn't be able to `Add` and `Remove` elements but you do not want that any other class can modify the conet of the list, only access and iterate them